# CredentialPicker.PickAsync not showing dialog

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I have the below code in the OnLaunched method of the app.xml.cs but the dialog is not shown at all, can somebody please advise:

```
CredentialPickerOptions credPickerOptions = new CredentialPickerOptions();
credPickerOptions.Message = Message.Text;
credPickerOptions.Caption = Caption.Text;
credPickerOptions.TargetName = Target.Text;
credPickerOptions.AlwaysDisplayDialog = (AlwaysShowDialog.IsChecked == true);
CredentialPickerOptions options = new CredentialPickerOptions()
{
    AuthenticationProtocol = AuthenticationProtocol.Basic,
    CredentialSaveOption = Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.CredentialSaveOption.Selected,
    CallerSavesCredential = true,
    Caption = "Basic Login",
    Message = "Please enter your credentials",
    TargetName = "."
};
CredentialPickerResults results = await CredentialPicker.PickAsync(options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The credentialPicker don't open full screen but on top of a page so you need to open it after the first page have been open. If you cannot open the main page of you application before the credential picker, you could just create a page with the image of you splash screen.